# A simple but most devious sequence puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

This is a question from a previous, now-defunct version of the [Temple of Quetzalcoatl](http://joezeng.com/quetzalcoatl/), that I've posted here as an exemplar of one of the difficult puzzles you might encounter while solving it.

---

The puzzle is simply this:

> 1845
>   6745
>   0738
>   0956
>   ????

What four-digit number goes into the question marks?

A hint in the source code was presented as such:

> -1

Comment: So many ideas...so many things to try... Is the solution obvious when you see it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Very obvious. Otherwise the puzzle wouldn't be so much evil as it would be unclear and unfair.

Comment: Not digging for too much of a hint, but can you do this without cultural/historical/etc knowledge? I'm not much good with dates and statistics, but if it's mostly logic and lateral thinking I'll keep mulling it over...

Comment: There are no dates or statistics in the puzzle, nor are any of them involved in the solution.

Comment: However, Google may be of use, as many of the problems in the Temple were intended to involve a little bit of research.

Comment: Just a really crazy guess, but is it 1845?

Comment: When I first created this puzzle, it was honestly intended as an easy puzzle to finish off the section. I had no idea it would give people such a hard time when I first made it.

Comment: "a brute-forcer was the first person to actually reach the next level of the puzzle" You mean that he tried all the numbers between 0 and 9999 until he found the answer?

Comment: Pretty much. But I know of at least three people who did actually solve it by logic.

Comment: I've exposed the plaintext because the temple no longer uses this puzzle. Have at it :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is

> 1617

Explanation:

> 2<sup>64</sup> = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616

This could be written as

> 1844 6744 0737 0955 1616

Then you just

> Add 1 to each of the numbers to get the numbers on the list, so the missing number is 1617

Comment: I have no idea how you could have possibly figured that out. Bravo.

Comment: That's exactly it. Good job figuring this out in less than two days.

Comment: I guess it's quite easy if you've memorised enough powers of 2...

Comment: This specific power of 2 is relatively notable as the answer to a problem involving grains of wheat and a chessboard.

Comment: Really? I'm disappointed by this being the solution. This was arbitrary and unclued, and the only way I imagine reaching it is by trying loads of equally arbitrary and unclued thing, or getting lucky. A clue at digits or powers of 2 or concatenation would have given some direction.

Comment: @xnor: That is somewhat true. However, the puzzles in the Temple aren't _entirely_ exemplary of the sort of puzzle that are suitable for this website, and sometimes their unclued nature is a part of that. This puzzle was definitely a bit too hard for what I intended it to be, and in my redesigned Temple I'm trying to make things clearer and less unfair.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> 9745

Explanation

> These are guesses made by someone in the cows-and-bulls game. In the first step, they got two bulls so they decided to change two numbers to see which positions are right. They got three bulls in the next step meaning that the digits kept fixed were right and one of the other digits was too. So they decided to keep one digit and two unseen digits in other places to figure out the fourth digit. They should have got one bull meaning that 7 was right and the other digits were all wrong. This left only 2 and 9 as possibilities for the first digit and hence they played a move with 9 and previously seen digits. They got a cow and thus the answer is 9745. this should be played in the last step to win.

Comment: Good guess, and very creative explanation (+1), but the pattern of the sequence has nothing to do with Mastermind.

Answer (score 0):

Each digit should appear twice, so I'm thinking of twice the missing digit and once each of one and nine.

I just don't find a logical sequence for the 4 digits.

Comment: 5 appears three times in the existing numbers.

Comment: ... and 3 appears only once.